# Extract information from SSIS xml file?

Tags: sql-server, xml, powershell, ssis

I'm trying to get the field list from a flat file source connection. I tried the following powershell command.

```
[xml]$p = cat .\package.dtsx
$p.Executable.ConnectionManager
```

And it returns

```
Property                                                    ObjectData
--------                                                    ----------
{DelayValidation, ObjectName, DTSID, Description...}        ObjectData
{DelayValidation, ObjectName, DTSID, Description...}        ObjectData
{DelayValidation, ObjectName, DTSID, Description...}        ObjectData
{DelayValidation, ObjectName, DTSID, Description...}        ObjectData
{DelayValidation, ObjectName, DTSID, Description...}        ObjectData
{DelayValidation, ObjectName, DTSID, Description...}        ObjectData
{DelayValidation, ObjectName, DTSID, Description...}        ObjectData
......
```

How to find the particular connection by name? I tried the following but it doesn't work.

```
# Find the connection which name is "XXX"
$p.Executable.ConnectionManager | % { $_.Property } | ? { $_.ObjectName -eq "XXX" }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By playing around, I sort of figured out the way to find a particular connection.

```
$c = $p.Executable.ConnectionManager | ? { $_.Property[1]."#text" -eq "XXX" }
```

Now need to get all the columns. The following statement get the xml.

```
$c.ObjectData.ConnectionManager.OuterXml
```

However, the data type is an integer.